How do you make cartoon eyelids disappear and appear in a rig?
I wonder if anyone knows how to make it like this picture below. For example,
 
I want the eyelid to move open to disappear and the close to appear. Also, I like the eyeball to move freely even with lids. It's for artistic choice.
Please add pictures or videos as an example.

i guess it depends on your armature, you could scale them down to 0 for example?

or move them inside the eye?
